# Web API 2 - Method now allowed(405) for PUT

Tags: c#, asp.net, webapi2

I am stuck with Web API 2 controller, from which I call `PUT` method and it gives me an error that method isn't allowed. I added lines of code in `Web.config` that prevent WebDAV to block methods. I tried everything but it is not working. It is probably problem with my `PUT` method in a controller.

Here is my controller code:

```
public IHttpActionResult Put(int id, [FromBody]ArticleModel model) {
    var article = _articleService.UpdateArticle(model);
    return Ok<ArticleModel>(article);
}
```

This is a code from where I call put :

```
  response = await client.PutAsJsonAsync("api/article/2", articleModel);
```

before this code I defined client as http and added needed properties,  and called other controller methods (GET, POST, DELETE) , they all work. This is from Windows Form app, and I am also calling from Postman but still the same error.

Comment: I think you just mixed up `Post` and `Put`. You can indeed use the same action for both verbs, but I personally think this is not a good practice in a web application (Post is there to create a new entity, Put should be used to update it). However, you can use both verbs to access the action. For an example there's [this link](https://www.exceptionnotfound.net/using-http-methods-correctly-in-asp-net-web-api/).

Comment: It is Put, i made typo .. :(

Comment: How are you creating your `PUT` request? Through a custom client? Through a web page? Through a dev tool like Postman/Fiddler?

Comment: Calling from Postman....but from Windows Form application too and still the same error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add `[HttpPut]` , `[RoutePrefix("api/yourcontroller")]` and `[Route("put")]` attribute to your controller method

Example:

```
[RoutePrefix("api/yourcontroller")]
public class YourController
{
 [HttpPut]   
 [Route("{id}/put")]
 public IHttpActionResult Put(int id, [FromBody]ArticleModel model) {
   var article = _articleService.UpdateArticle(model);
   return Ok<ArticleModel>(article);
 }
}
```

**EDIT 1**

```
public class YourController
{
 [HttpPut]   
 [Route("api/article/{id}/put")]
 public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> Put(int id, [FromBody]ArticleModel model) {
   var article = _articleService.UpdateArticle(model);
   return Ok<ArticleModel>(article);
 }
}
```

From your HttpRequest call It seems what is expected is a `HttpResponseMessage` So changed the return type to `async Task<HttpResponseMessage>`

Code for making HttpRequest:

```
response = await client.PutAsJsonAsync("api/article/2/put", articleModel);
```

Comment: Please add the code from which you are making the request  in the question

Comment: Please look at EDIT 1

Answer (score 1):

Add the  [`[System.Web.Http.HttpPut]`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.http.httpputattribute%28v=vs.118%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) attribute to your method.